# N body simulation

Tags: differential-equations, astronomy

I'm trying to solve a 3 body problem consisting of the earth moon and sun.
I'm wanting to show the earth orbiting the sun and the moon orbiting the earth as a result of the gravitational forces.

Where Force due to gravity is given by:

$$\mathbf F_{ij}=\frac{Gm_i m_j}{\|\mathbf q_j-\mathbf q_i\|^2}\cdot\frac{(\mathbf q_j-\mathbf q_i)}{\|\mathbf q_j-\mathbf q_i\|}=\frac{Gm_i m_j(\mathbf q_j-\mathbf q_i)}{\|\mathbf q_j-\mathbf q_i\|^3}$$

And the acceleration of the bodies can be given as

$$\vec{a}_j=\sum_{i\ne j}^n G\frac{M_i}{\left|\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j\right|^3}\left(\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j\right)$$

**INITIAL CONDITIONS**

The initial conditions of the bodies are as follows:

```
Ecc = {0.01671022, 0.00549}(*eccentricity of earth and moon orbits*);
Inc = {0.00005, 5.145};
RAAN = {-11.260640, 0};
ArgPer = {102.94719, 0};
G = 0.00029589743849552926`;(*gravitational constant in AU*)
m = {1, 3.004*10^-6, 
  3.694*10^-8}; (*mass of sun, earth and moon in solar    masses*)
μ = Table[
G*m[[i]], {i, 1, 3}];(*standard gravitational parameter of *)
(*μ={8.8878*10^-10, 1.093*10^-11};*)(*standard gravitational \
constant\[Rule] Sunm, earth, moon*)    
ψ = 0;
a = {1.00000011, 0.99743};(*semi major axis in AU*);
r = a (1 - Ecc^2)/(1 + 
Ecc Cos[ψ])(* disatances for sun to earth and sun to moon 
in AU*)
rx = r Cos[ψ](* x component of distance for: sun to earth and \
sun to moon*);
ry = r Sin[ψ](* y component of distance forsun to earth and sun \
to moon*);
v = Table[
Sqrt[μ[[i]] (2/r[[i]] - 1/a[[i]])], {i, 
2}](*earth velocity due to sun , moon velocity due to earth units of AU/day*)
T = {365.2, 27}(*earth moon period in days*);
```

**EQUATIONS OF MOTION**

```
Nbody = Table[
  NDSolve[{(x''[t] + (
  G*m[[i]]*x[t])/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(3/2) + (
  G*m[[j]]* (x[t]))/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(3/2) == 
 0, (y^''[
  t] == -((G*m[[i]] (y[t]))/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(3/2)) - (
  G*m[[j]] (y[t]))/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(3/2), x[0] == rx[[i]], 
y[0] == ry[[i]], [x]'[0] == 0, 
[y]'[0] == v[[i]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 365.2}], {i, 
2}, {j, 2}]
```

I can plot the results using  `

```
plot2D = Show[
Table[ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. Nbody[[i]]], {t, 0, T[[i]]}(*,
 PlotStyle\[Rule]None*), PlotRange -> 1.1], {i, 2}]];
 Animate[Show[plot2D, 
 Graphics[Table[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
 Point[{x[t], y[t]} /. Nbody[[i]]]}, {i, 2}]]], {t, 0, 365.2}, 
 AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

However I get this graph
 Along with the error message

```
ReplaceAll::reps: {{{{x->InterpolatingFunction[{<<1>>},{<<13>>},{<<1>>},{<<3>>},{<<1>>}],y->InterpolatingFunction[{<<1>>},{<<13>>},{<<1>>},{<<3>>},{<<1>>}]}}}[[2]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Coordinate ReplaceAll[{$CellContext`x[0], $CellContext`y[0]}, Part[{{{$CellContext`x -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 365.2}}, {5, 7, 2, {84}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False}, {{0., 0.011199207293206922`, 0.022398414586413843`, 0.27915745480600035`, 0.5359 should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

**What I think is wrong**

From the graph, the orbit of the earth is correct. The orbit of the moon should be around the earth which obviously it's not!

From section of Code for Nbody;

The masses for the sun and the moon are correct
However I think the respective vectors for each body are not.

What I think I need to do is find a way for apply the initial conditions to both bodies individually, which I don't think I've done using this code.

Would anyone be able to help in correcting this?

Thank you for your time.

[image: plot with error]

Comment: The variable `planet` is used in the `Graphics[ ... ]` expression, but `planet` is not defined in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i've corrected the error however, the original problem still remains.

Comment: `(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]`  is wrong, output  only looks like  `Derivative[2][x][t]`! That's why `NBody`isn't evaluated!

Comment: Even with x''[t], y''[t], x'[0], y'[0], the problem remains,
thank you for your reply, and your patience!

Comment: If you have access to M12, why don't you try using [`NBodySimulation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulation) instead?

Comment: Good evening, if this works i would like to introduce other bodies to the simulation to see how well it works. I would like to do this without the use of 'NbodySimulation'

Comment: I’m at a loss what to try but I will try swapping NDSolve and table. Thank you for your reply, any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Substituting the equation for force into Newton’s second law and solving for acceleration will remove the second mass. so if this was a 2 body system and the acceleration on earth m_e due to the sun M, was used then as per Newton’s law the equation of motion would be x’’(t) + GMx/(x^2+y^2)^(3/2)=0. I’ve not used q_i - q_j as I’ve taken the Initial position of the bodies as the distance from the origin at 0. Which is the same as q_i -q_j, just a different format. <This should have been posted before my last comment>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solving the problem requires high accuracy in determining the initial data. All parameters can be determined using `StarData["Sun", "..."], PlanetData["Earth", "..."], \
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "..."]`,For example, mass

```
m = {StarData["Sun", "Mass"], PlanetData["Earth", "Mass"], 
  PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "Mass"]}

(*Out[]= {Quantity[1.988435*10^30, "Kilograms"], 
 Quantity[5.972*10^24, "Kilograms"], 
 Quantity[7.3459*10^22, "Kilograms"]}*)
```

Gravitational Constant Mass Product

```
 mG = {StarData["Sun", "GravitationalConstantMassProduct"], 
  PlanetData["Earth", "GravitationalConstantMassProduct"], 
  PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "GravitationalConstantMassProduct"]};

 mG = mG // QuantityMagnitude

(*Out[]= {1.327124400*10^20, 3.98600436*10^14, 4.9028*10^12}*}
```

So I defined all the parameters

```
μ = {0.00029591220828349645438389263285760599`10.122911634152604, 
  8.8876924487802410900708441245`8.697447781980085*^-10, 
  1.0931894685338682`*^-11}; (*standard gravitational parameter of \
sun,earth and moon in AU*)
rx = {0, 0.9832672274945706, 
  0.9847793657772581}(*x and y components of initial position*);
ry = {0, 0, 0.0020731551812556903};
vy = {0, 0.017491119160350586, 0.017965913470733775}; vx = {0, 
  0, -0.0003463101361750346`}(*initial velocities of earth and moon*);
eq = {Table[
    x[i]''[t] == 
     Sum[If[j == i, 
       0, (-μ[[j]] (x[i][t] - 
          x[j][t]))/((x[i][t] - x[j][t])^2 + (y[i][t] - y[j][t])^2)^(
       3/2)], {j, 3}], {i, 3}], 
   Table[y[i]''[t] == 
     Sum[If[j == i, 
       0, (-μ[[j]] (y[i][t] - 
          y[j][t]))/((x[i][t] - x[j][t])^2 + (y[i][t] - y[j][t])^2)^(
       3/2)], {j, 3}], {i, 3}]};
var = Join[Table[x[i], {i, 3}], Table[y[i], {i, 3}]];

orb = NDSolve[{eq, 
   Table[x[i][0] == rx[[i]], {i, 3}], 
   Table[y[i][0] == ry[[i]], {i, 3}], 
   Table[x[i]'[0] == vx[[i]], {i, 3}], 
   Table[y[i]'[0] == vy[[i]], {i, 3}]}, var, {t, 0, 366}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 10^-3]
```

The orbit of the earth and moon

```
{ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{{var[[2]][t], var[[5]][t]}, {var[[3]][t], 
      var[[6]][t]}} /. First[orb]], {t, 0, 365}], 
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{var[[2]][t] - var[[3]][t], var[[5]][t] - var[[6]][t]} /. 
    First[orb]], {t, 0, 27.322}]}
```

There is still insufficient accuracy for the orbit of the moon
[image: Figure 1]

Some details of calculating input parameters.

1.Calculate the solstice date

```
PlanetData["Earth", "PeriapsisTime"]

(*Out[]= DateObject[{2020, 1, 5}, "Day", "Gregorian", -4.]*)
```

2. Calculate the coordinates and speed of the earth and moon

   ```
   PlanetData["Earth", 
    EntityProperty["Planet", 
     "VelocityAroundSun", {"Date" -> DateObject[DateList[{2020, 1, 8}]]}]]
   PlanetData["Earth", 
    EntityProperty["Planet", 
     "DistanceFromSun", {"Date" -> DateObject[DateList[{2020, 1, 8}]]}]]
   (*Quantity[30.28511785356967`, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")]
   Quantity[0.9832672274945706`, "AstronomicalUnit"]*)


   PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
    EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", 
     "DistanceFromSun", {"Date" -> DateObject[DateList[{2020, 1, 8}]]}]]
    (*Quantity[0.985403, "AstronomicalUnit"]*)
   PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
    EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", 
     "SunElongation", {"Date" -> DateObject[DateList[{2020, 1, 8}]]}]]

   (*Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{143, 49, 27.613}], 
    MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}]]*)

    PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "AverageOrbitVelocity"]

    (*Quantity[1.02, ("Kilometers")/("Seconds")]*)
    PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
    EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", 
     "DistanceFromEarth", {"Date" -> DateObject[DateList[{2020, 1, 8}]]}]]

   (*Quantity[383873., "Kilometers"]*)
   ```

   We use geometry to calculate the coordinates and speed of the moon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex. May i ask how you derived the expressions for vx and vy for the moon? Did you use the expression for orbital velocity that I used?

Comment: @Luke4737 See update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight alex, ive been able to make an N-body simulation for the solar system.
Theres an interesting quirk where all planets begin to drift  with the sun after an approximate period of 30000 days. As a result of this drift, pluto never reaches its aphelion of  49.3 AU yet still completes a full orbit. If i can discover the error behind this i believe it'll work. would you like to see?

Comment: @Luke4737 Open a new theme for a simulation of 30,000 days.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208358/solar-system-n-body-simulation

Comment: I think a symplectic method for `NDSolve` will do better to keep energy conservation. A built-in reference: ["SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html)