# NDsolve for differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Im attempting to use the `NDSolve` funtction to solve a coupled system of 2nd order differential equations. The differential equations are the for the acceleration of a body due to the gravitational forces of other bodies

Where

[image]

and

[image]

**variables**

```
μ = 
 {0.00029591220828349645438389263285760599`10.122911634152604, 
  8.8876924487802410900708441245`8.697447781980085*^-10, 
  1.0931894685338682`*^-11}; 
rx = {0, 0.9832672274945706, 0.9847793657772581}
v = {0, 0.017491119160350586, 0.017965913470733775};
```

**Code for NDSolve**

```
eqn = 
 {x[i]''[t] == 
    Sum[
      If[j == i, 
        0, 
        (-μ[[j]] (x[i][t] - x[j][t]))/((x[i][t] - x[j][t])^2 + (y[i][t] - y[j][t])^2)^(3/2)], 
      {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 
  y[i]''[t] == 
    Sum[
      If[j == i, 
        0, 
        (-μ[[j]] (y[i][t] - y[j][t]))/((x[i][t] - x[j][t])^2 + (y[i][t] - y[j][t])^2)^(3/2)], 
      {i, 3}, {j, 3}]};

var = Table[{x[0] == rx[[i]], y[0] == 0,[x]'[0] == 0, [y]'[0] == v[[i]]}, {i, 3}]

soln = Table[NDSolve[{eqn, var, {x[i], y[i]}}, {t, 0, 365.2}], {i, 3}];
```

**Problem**

When I run this, I recieve the following error:

> NDSolve::argm: NDSolve called with 2 arguments; 3 or more arguments are expected.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Don't wrap all the arguments to `NDSolve` in `{}`.

Comment: So it should be: `soln = Table[NDSolve[eqn, var, {x[i], y[i]}, {t, 0, 365.2}], {i, 3}]; ?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: its a system of coupled ODE's to show the acceleration of a body due to gravitational forces of other bodies, ive updated the question with more detail. I hope this helps

Comment: To get three arguments, try moving one brace: `NDSolve[{eqn, var}, {x[i], y[i]}, {t, 0, 365.2}]`

Comment: thank you for your reply, by altering the code as your suggesstion, i recieve a different error message: NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {x[1][t],x[2][t],x[3][t],y[1][t],y[2][t],y[3][t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.

Comment: @Luke4737 There is a typo in `eqn`. Use my code from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208322/n-body-simulation